# Are Mobile Geodatabases Readable and Editable using ArcGIS Field Maps

Tags: editing, sqlite, arcgis-field-maps, arcgis-runtime-sdk-android

The 100.12 release notes for Android state it can  [Read and edit standalone mobile geodatabases](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/reference/release-notes/100.12/#read-and-edit-standalone-mobile-geodatabases)

We were able to sideload them to a directory within our mobile app and read and edit it in our ArcGIS Runtime API for Android app, but not Field Maps.

For it to work in Field Maps, it seems they may have to be part of a mmpk but then is the mobile geodatabase really standalone?

Comment: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/geodatabases/manage-mobile-gdb/mobile-geodatabases.htm

Comment: @PolyGeo of course I read that help link before posting. It still doesn't answer my question.

Comment: What is the single question that you wish to ask?  I put that link in as a comment because I thought it had an answer to your first one.